# Executing network request once cellForItemAtIndexPath is completed for CollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, uicollectionview

I have a collection view that in which a cell is  populated based on an array of int's.

After the cells are created I want to check for parameters for each cell via network request.

At the moment I carry out the network request for each cell in this method and it causes a cell to be created before its parameters are assigned due to inconsistent networks.

Is there a method to run a network function (sendGetPar:) on completion of laying out the cells? Obviously this can then be reused when the user scrolls etc.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    BOOL isFocusOn = [_userDefault boolForKey:@"mixFocusOn"];
    if (isFocusOn == TRUE) {
        CDCChannelStrip *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSNumber *setChan = [self.focusChannels objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        NSInteger chanInt = [setChan intValue] +1;
        cell.clipsToBounds = YES;
        [cell initData:(chanInt)];
        [self.mixMonitorView setChannelsStripToType:(cell)];
        [self.mixMonitorView sendGetPar:chanInt];
        return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate?language=objc) would be helpful 
probably the methods:
`collectionView:didEndDisplayingCell:forItemAtIndexPath:`

> Tells the delegate that the specified cell was removed from the collection view.

`collectionView:didUpdateFocusInContext:withAnimationCoordinator:`

> Tells the delegate that a focus update occurred.

Comment: removing the cell isnt relevant its just after adding a cell, ill look at the focus func but that doesnt seem like what id need either

Comment: Then I think you could include a function call just before the last line of
`collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` . This funtion call will execute the network request, you could also pass any parameters to this function. eg the index of the cell that was just laid out.

Comment: edited my answer, please check if this works for you. tested it, worked for me. It will only call the function `sendGetPar` for the views that are visible at the moment, as  you scroll, the appropriate `index` would be passed and your network request can be made. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    BOOL isFocusOn = [_userDefault boolForKey:@"mixFocusOn"];
    if (isFocusOn == TRUE) {
        CDCChannelStrip *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSInteger chanInt = indexPath.row +1;
        cell.clipsToBounds = YES;
        [cell initData:(chanInt)];
        [self.mixMonitorView setChannelsStripToType:(cell)];
        [self.mixMonitorView sendGetPar:chanInt];
        return cell;
}
-(void) sendGetPar:(NSInteger)index // you could return the parameter via this method. 
{
    NSLog(@"Parameter:%ld", (long)index);
}
```

Comment: your additional line is just rewriting what [self.mixMonitorView sendGetPar:chanInt]; does

Comment: Oh, okay, but check if the `value` that is being passed to `sendGetPar`. It could be possible that the value sent isn't returning any response for the network method. Deleted my line from the code.

Comment: Here's a [link] (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6t-vrovYpogZDJWQkRnb3duOVU) to the sample project